# SQL Server Alter login

Tags: sql-server

I want to change password of SQL Server login and want not to apply the windows password protection policy. I wonder why I'm not able to find an example even after googling out so much. :(

```
ALTER LOGIN <login name> WITH PASSWORD = '<password here>' CHECK_POLICY Off;
```

I get this error.

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Off'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax, as the error message tells you. Check the [relevant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189828.aspx) MSDN pages (which is always a good idea before posting here, btw): you need to put an equal sign between the CHECK_POLICY keyword and the OFF and you are missing a comma.

```
ALTER LOGIN <login name> WITH PASSWORD = '<password here>', CHECK_POLICY = Off;
```

Comment: Good point about the missing comma. It's not always immediately apparent from the docs.